# How to show selected value in a mapped Select menu-item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem I cannot solve now for some days, so I decided to ask the community to get an answer.
The data to the select is coming from an API.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    selectedAnswer: '',
    selectedAnswers: [],
    selectedSymptom: '',
  }
}

handleAnswerSelect = (event) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
      selectedAnswers: [...prevState.selectedAnswers,
        this.state.selectedAnswer],
    }
  })
}


symptomQuestionsAnswers.Questions.map((question, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={question.Id}>
    <InputLabel className={classes.selectLabel}>
      <p style={{ marginTop: '15px', marginBottom: 0 }}>
        {question.Question}</p>
    </InputLabel>

    <FormControl
      key={question.Id}
      fullWidth
      className={classes.selectFormControl}>
      <Select
        MenuProps={{ className: classes.selectMenu }}
        classes={{ select: classes.select }}
        value={this.state.selectedAnswer}
        id={question.id}
        inputProps={{
          name: "selectedAnswer",
        }}
        onChange={this.handleAnswerSelect}>
        {question.Answers.map(answer => (
          <MenuItem
            key={answer.Id}
            classes={{
              root: classes.selectMenuItem,
              selected: classes.selectMenuItemSelected,
            }}
            value={answer.Id}>
            {answer.Answer}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
        }
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </React.Fragment>
))
```

I would like to show the selected item on each selection.
At the moment selecting the second select's menu item removes the first one from the selection.
I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Might be you need the multiple select?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make multiple select using `Material UI`.

In such case you need to add `multiple` property to `Select` component.

E.g.:

```
<Select
  MenuProps={{ className: classes.selectMenu }}
  classes={{ select: classes.select }}
  value={this.state.selectedAnswer}
  id={question.id}
  inputProps={{ name: "selectedAnswer" }}
  onChange={this.handleAnswerSelect}
  // here it is
  multiple
>
  {question.Answers.map(answer => (
    <MenuItem
      key={answer.Id}
      classes={{
        root: classes.selectMenuItem,
        selected: classes.selectMenuItemSelected
      }}
      value={answer.Id}
    >
      {answer.Answer}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
  }
</Select>
```

See more in [docs](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/).